# Tomcat6 not accessible on browser installed on EC2

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redhat

I successfully installed tomcat6 on my ec2 but I am unable to access its page on my browser.

while running  `netstat -nlp|grep 8080`
I get this output

(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=502 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      -

Is there anything which I am missing.

Comment: So the browser is installed on the same EC2 instance as the Tomcat server? What URL are you trying to use to visit your site?

Comment: I am visiting the server url and I am trying it on my machine.Port is 8080

Comment: So the browser is installed on the same EC2 instance as the Tomcat server? What URL are you trying to use to visit your site?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to set firewall settings. please follow if you re not done...[EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah/getting-started-security-group.html)

Comment: Is there any way I can do it through the terminal.

Comment: you need to set up AWS AMI tools in order to run following commands.

To enable port 8080
     "ec2-authorize default -p 8080"

to disable port 8080
     "ec2-revoke default -p 8080"